# Object to System.String implicit conversion

Tags: c#

I have a question regarding type conversion in C#.

```
Object data_obj = "test";
string data_str;
data_str = data_obj;
```

this produces an error claiming no implicit conversion exists. Now, this is, at least for me, a little bit unintuitive, since `Console.WriteLine("type{0}",data_obj.GetType())` produces  `System.String`, but then again, i am really new at C#.

Now, getting past this, i would like to cast to the type of the data stored in `data_obj`, without having to `switch` and selecting the type manually.

So, basically, what i am asking is: is there a way to define an implicit conversion from `System.Object` to `System.String`, `System.Decimal`, etc.

Context:

I am reading from an ODBC connection to an SQLServer database and trying to pump those rows into an Oracle Database. Now, the correspondence of SQLServer and Oracle rows have to be defined. Now, i read the data from the SQLServer table with no problem whatsoever, and i store it in a `List<Dictionary<string,Object>>` (i know, storing the rows seem wrong, but design requirements, what can you do). 
The insertion part is where i am having problems with the insertion. I basically loop (with a foreach) through the elements of the list and insert them row by row. It is here where i need to determine the type of the data stored in the `Object`.

Edit: Including a bit more detail.

Comment: Even if you could add an implicit conversion, all you would be doing would be saving yourself having to write `(string)` (or whatever type). You'd still have to figure out what type it is if you wanted to store it in a variable, and that variable would have to be defined as that type, so you'd need to have a `switch` or `if` statements for that anyways.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, there's no way of doing it implicitly. Options:

- Call `ToString()` explicitly (which will throw an exception if the reference is null)
- Call `Convert.ToString()`
- Use `"" + data_obj` (ick, don't do it)
- Cast if you're sure that `data_obj` is *really* a string

Why are you so keen on an implicit conversion though?

Comment: I am just lazy. I have data to insert to a database table, and i wanted to do it at one fell swoop. I think i am going to do it the long way.

Comment: @horacv: I suspect there may well be a better way of doing this, but it's hard to know what that is without more context. If you edit more details into the question, we may be able to help more.

Answer (score 2):

What you should be doing in your code as noted above is `casting`, not `converting`. The object in question *is* a string; you simply have stored it in an `object` reference.

Casting would be done like so:

```
data_str = (string)data_obj;
```

The overload of `Console.Writeline` you are mentioning takes a format string, and then a params array of `object`... not strings. It calls `ToString()` on each of those objects. So your call to `data_obj.GetType().ToString()` could be slimmed down to `data_obj.GetType()` (calling ToString() on a string just returns the string again)

As for an implicit conversion from `object` to type `x`... think about what you are asking; a reference of `object` can be any CLR type. How do you handle those conversions?

Comment: I am not sure i understand what you mean by "handle those conversions". It the lvalue is string and the rvalue es an object storing a string there should be no problem.

Comment: "can be *literally anything*" - Not to be picky, but it can't be a pointer.

Comment: +1 Adam ; I try to be more precise than that. Editing now to say "can be any CLR type"

Comment: @horacv : Again, you are not converting there... you are casting. (at least, you shouldn't be converting in this case; it's pointless). The problem is, the compiler really has no way to know that the `object` reference you are passing it is a `string`, because it could be any CLR type at all. By forcing you to explicitly cast it, you are telling the compiler, "It's OK, I know this is going to be a `string` so go ahead and do this..." and if you are wrong, you'll get an Exception

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with "no way to know". It most definitely has a way of knowing, what type of data an ``Object`` contains, since it can infer it by the type of data of the value this ``Object`` gets assigned.

Comment: *Perhaps* it could do that in your extremely simple example. But in most real-world cases, it can not. But your example isn't a failing of the compiler; it's a failing of the programmer. If you know it's a string, declare it as a string, not an object.

Comment: I see your recent edit; You seem to indicate you don't even know what types the objects are... how do you expect the compiler to automatically know and cast for you? You need to test to find out what types they really are, and cast them appropriately.

Comment: I am most definitely sure the problem lies with the programmer! However, i am not sure how one could keep ``Object`` from knowing what it is stored.

Comment: And yes, i do know the types, so there is actually no problem with casting them to their right type, however, if there is a way of doing this automatically, it would save a lot of work.

Comment: `object` "know what it stores" all the time, (sticking with the loose vernacular, here). But you need to be clear to the compiler as far as what you want done with it, and in what context. If `object` did not know what it stored, you couldn't get an exception when you tried to cast or convert a `System.IO.FileInfo` object to an `Int32`. So yes - it "knows". But it assumes that if you told it, "Consider this string to be an object" that you meant for it to be that way, so it does so until you tell it otherwise.

Comment: I am sorry, i don't follow anymore. You mentioned that i most real-world cases C# could not know the type of the ``object`` reference, and then you mentioned it could know. Now, C#, as little as i understand, knows everything there is to know about the type of an expression at Compile-time. This is why i thought i would be able to assign the ``object``   holding a ``string``   directly to a ``string``.

Comment: I am sorry! i know now where my problem lies! The GetType() is actually done at Run-time!.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Convert.ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/astxcyeh.aspx) method:

```
object o = ...
string s = Convert.ToString(o);
```

Comment: @George, there's no implicit conversion possible.

Answer (score 0):

There is no implicit conversion from `object` to `string` in C#. However you could call the object's virtual `ToString` method

```
string s = o.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you store your value in a var instead of type object and let the compiler decide what the value is, then it can be made implicit.

```
var data_obj = "test";
string data_str;
data_str = data_obj;
```